# How to call a CGI function on HTML button click

Tags: html, cgi

I have an HTML form. I have a Submit button which calls a CGI script(function), defined and declared in a C file.

Similarly, I want to call a "save function"(CGI script) on save button click.
So, my question is how can I call a CGI script on button click on HTML form.

I am a newbie to HTML and CGI, but need to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the data of HTML form to your CGI file via GET or POST request. For example;

```
<form action="cgi-bin/save.cgi" method="post">
```

When you click to save button, it'll call the save.cgi